# unity 500 internal server error

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine

i have just installed unity to create games, but when i pressed 30-day free trail is says **500 - internal server error**. and now when i open it i comes up directly. i tried Unity 4.3.4 and Unity 4.6.1 it gives same result.

also tried manual activation, but the console says **https://license.unity3d.com/manual Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server was down.
It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Hey yeah I got the same problem today I guess there is a bug in unity you can wait for them to fix it or just keep trying it may work out as it did to me just keep doing it and I think that will help if it doesn't just wait for the bug fix